# Derivative of $\sqrt[3]{(x-1)(x+2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\sqrt[3]{(x-1)(x+2)^2} = (x-1)^\frac 1 3 (x+2)^\frac 2 3$$

Applying the product rule:

$$f'(x) = \frac 1 3 (x-1)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(x+2)^\frac 2 3 + \frac 2 3(x-1)^\frac 1 3 (x+2)^{-\frac 1 3}$$

Negative powers in the denominator and a common denominator:

$$= \frac{(x+2)^\frac 1 3 (x+2)^\frac 2 3 + 2(x-1)^\frac 1 3 (x-1)^\frac 2 3}{3 (x-1)^\frac 2 3 (x+2)^\frac 1 3} = \frac{x+2+2x-2}{3 (x-1)^\frac 2 3 (x+2)^\frac 1 3}$$

Further simplify:

$$= \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{(x+2)(x-1)^2}}$$

Is this solution correct? If not, why and what's the correct solution?

Comment: It seems correct to me and Wolfram also confirms it so you didn't make a calculation error or something like that. Well done! (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx(((x-1)(x%2B2)%5E2)%5E(1%2F3)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct, but I wanted to point this is a typical case where *logarithmic differentiation* makes the computation both simpler and safer:
$$\frac{f'}f=\frac13\Bigl(\frac 1{x-1}+\frac 2{x+2}\Bigr)=\frac1{\not3} \,\frac{\not3x}{(x-1)(x+2)},$$
so $$f'=\frac{f'}f\,f=\frac x{(x-1)(x+2)}\,(x-1)^{\tfrac13}(x+2)^{\tfrac23}=
\frac x{(x-1)^{\tfrac23}(x+2)^{\tfrac13}}=\frac x{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^{2}(x+2)\strut}}.$$

Comment: What are the cases when I can use logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: Mainly when the function is a product and quotient of powers (not  necessarily integer powers) of simple functions of the variable. For the step, it eliminates all powers, changing them into factors.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have correctly applied the product rule and simplified it, your solution is correct. Cheers!

Well, next time you can check on [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com).